# difference between request.getParameter() and form.get()

Tags: java, jsp, struts

I have a basic doubt in struts 1.x

Is there any difference in getting the value from jsp using `request.getParameter('name')` and `form.get('name')`, in terms of efficiency.

I know that `form.get()` returns an object and the former a string.

I want to know in the action class is it worth to get the dynaActionForm from the form argument of execute method and use it to get the user entered values in jsp. Or request.getParameter is enough ? Is there any other use of form object, if I typecast and create one ?

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use request.getParameter().